# External CSS + Google font

Tags: html, css

For some reason, the Google font that is imported doesn't work?  The font isn't displayed correctly.  Here is the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="/main.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="testing">
   <h1>nothing to see</h1>
  </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

My CSS file:

```
.testing h1 {
font-family: 'Pacifico';
font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Where IS the css file? Is it in the folder *above* your html file? Or is it in the *same* folder as your html file? If it's in the same folder, remove the `/` from the link: `<link href="main.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">`

Comment: Bah.  Yes it is in the same folder as the html file.  Thanks for the second set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second link tag(the one containing main.css) has the wrong address to main.css. Try putting main.css in the same folder as your HTML file and delete the slash(/) right next to the href value main.css as shown

`<link href="main.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">`

If you want your CSS inside of a seperate file insert the code as shown

```
<link href="(FILE NAME)/main.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

use correct path for main.css
make css folder & put main css file in that folder & use below path

`<link href="css/main.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">`